# IntelliJ IDE compiles another first and if it does not have any error it compiles the one I clicked for

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a project named "Another one". It has 2 programs which do not have any relation with each other. The programs are "abc.java" and "def.java".
Both programs are for printing "Hello  World". 
If "abc.java" does not have any mistakes then only the compiler compiles "def.java",even though "def.java" does not have any mistakes.
Do I have to create one project for each program I make. I am new to programming.

[def.java works fine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flR3V.png)

[when I removed a semicolon from abc.java, def.java stops working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MrnW.png)

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD6RP.png)

[Module Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4MY6.png)

Comment: A project should contain the code that builds a single application. If abc.java and def.java are meant to be 2 different applications, they should be in different projects. Alternatively, you could add modules to a project, so you could have a module for each java application, but see both of them in the same project. See the help for modules for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in IntelliJ you don't think in terms of "programs", but in terms of "project" and "modules". The most basic one is a project where the single module is located where the project is located (e.g. Project at **D:\projects\MyProjects** with 1 module at **D:\projects\MyProjects**).

[image: Structure 1]

[image: Structure 2]

[image: Project]

What I can think of going wrong:

- Your module containing abc.java is not actually a module. if you can execute abc.java with a run configuration, it should be a module.
- Your build settings are somewhat wrong.

Compiler errors should keep you from executing the program to prevent misbehaviour in your application. For me, I can only not execute a module if the other modules have any compiler error while also being a dependency for the executing module. But not sure if a tool/plugin is causing this behaviour.

Also, you can check if you set up your modules correctly. Check the image above if your configuration looks similiar.

I hope I can help you. If not, maybe update your post providing some screenshots of your setup and configurations as I have shown you.

Comment: Hey, I have added some screenshots. It would be very helpful if you can see what's wrong. Everything looks similar to your setup. Earlier I used "Blue J",it was very simple, I just needed to click on "compile" and it worked, this is quite alien to me. Thank you anyways

Comment: Looking at the screenshots, I assume you have both abc and def in your src folder. If so, you need to create a new run configurations in the top-right corner where it says "def" at the moment, using the abc class as the main class. I assume that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Get your definitions and terms right before doing anything else.

And then tell people what you're actually doing.

As stated, IntelliJ (and indeed all modern IDEs) have modules and projects. When you execute a target in a module, that entire module gets built IF NEEDED.

> If "abc.java" does not have any mistakes then only the compiler compiles "def.java",even though "def.java" does not have any mistakes

This does not make any sense whatsoever. The compiler will compile whatever needs compiling. But most likely you're not talking about compiling, you're clicking the "run" button which will run whatever it is configured to run.

If you only have 1 run configuration set up, that's what will ALWAYS be run pressing that button.
If you want to run something without creating an explicit run configuration, just right click the open source file and select "Run".

This will cause ALL changed sources in the module to be compiled, no mumbo jumbo about it "compiling x despite y not having errors".
It will also attempt to compile everything that does have errors, and fail.